# How to set the AVAssetWriter with a maxduration and change the URL

Tags: avfoundation, avassetwriter

I want to record the movie from the camera. Just use the demo Rosywriter apple supply. But what I want to do is set the maxduration of the record and when the duration reaches the maxduration, the AVAssetWriter can change the URL to write the movie to another file. But the problem is  the URL is readonly and I can't change it. I know that there is another method to do this is add a movieFileOutput to the AVCaptureSession. But I need to process the PixelBuffer before it's recorded. So I need to add a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput in stead. How can I achieve that? I have to apologize for my poor English.